# Deconstructing a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

A JSON encoded array is passed from PHP to an HTML document.  It is not at all clear how to deconstruct that array into javascript-usable pieces.  For example, consider the following HTML:

`<div id="options">{"foo":[{"id":1},{"id":3}], "bar":[{"id":2},{"id":4}]}</div>`

The only *a priori* known element of this array is that the key `id` exists. The indices, I know, can be found with

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#options").text());
$.each(data, function(index) {
  // index will be foo & bar
});
```

The use case is to use the index and id to add an attribute to elements in a document. I have not yet stumbled upon the technique to return the ids associated with each index. How best can that be done?

## Edit - a clarification of the use case - the long story

I want to re-enable some options on a form based on properties of an entity (in a Symfony application).  Disabled options cannot be modified, but are also not not persisted - their values are set to null.  I've built a service to determine the option elements that are disabled and send those elements to the form document as a JSON object.  I'm assuming for now that the specific options are not known until the form is created.  In the example above, `foo` & `bar` represent possible options, and the ids correspond to the option.  For example, a `Household` entity might have `Reason` options selected but disabled of "Low wages" (id = 3).  This would show up in as `...id="options">{"reasons":[{"id":3}]}<...`.  I would the use this information to remove the `disabled="disabled"` attribute from the set of checkboxes for the Reason, id=3 (i.e., `id="household_reasons_3"`) field.  I hope this makes sense.

### Edit #2, by request - the PHP code creating the object.

The result of `getMetatData()` appears in the document at `#options`.  From the above edit, the Household entity is `$object`.

```
public function getMetaData($object) {
    $data = array();
    $className = get_class($object);
    $metaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata($className);
    foreach ($metaData->associationMappings as $field => $mapping) {
        if (8 === $mapping['type']) {
            $data[$field] = $this->extractOptions($object, $field);
        }
    }

    return json_encode($data);
}

private function extractOptions($object, $field) {
    $data = [];
    $method = 'get' . ucfirst($field);
    $itemName = substr($field, 0, -1);
    $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($itemName);
    $entity = $object->$method();
    foreach ($entity as $item) {
        if (method_exists($item, 'getEnabled') && false === $item->getEnabled()) {
            $data[] = ['id' => $item->getId()];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are you just wanting the entire array with IDs for each property, or each individual one with its parent key (i.e. "foo", or "bar")?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do with that object. Once you parse it you have an object with properties `foo` and `bar`, then what do you want to do? Iterate the keys?

Comment: `The use case is to use the index and id to add an attribute to elements in a document ` - does that mean you want to add attributes to html elements - e.g. `<div id="1">`, `<div id="3">` etc.?

Comment: Need a better reference to match the elements to your data as well as expected results. Not enough known. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Agree with the above comments-- what would be helpful would be either a clear explanation of what you are looking for, or perhaps an example snippet showing what you'd like the output to look like.

Comment: What would you like the output to be? Either post some JSON for the object you want to construct that you consider a "javascript-usable piece", or post the initial document and what the document should look like after you updated it.

Comment: I've edited the question in an effort to clarify the use case.  It's clear that I'd abstracted the question a bit too far.  If it needs to be even more concrete I can do that, too.

Comment: Why is it set in HTML to start? Seems like a good way to have XSS. Why is it not just an Object to start?

Comment: JSON stands for _JavaScript Object Notation_ so it is already JavaScript.  Is there a reason you are using an html text element rather than a js variable inside a script tag?  It would be interesting to see your relevant lines of PHP.

Comment: @Phil_1984_  FWIW, I've added the PHP code.

Comment: @epascarello I'm open to any working solution.  At least for now I have zero proficiency in XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long before the infinite monkey limit was reached I stumbled on a method to create the results I was looking for. My thanks go out to all who pushed for clarifications. So, for the object

`{"foo":[{"id":1},{"id":3}], "bar":[{"id":2},{"id":4}]}`

the script

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#options").text());
var i = 0
var output = [];
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  $.each(item, function(k, v) {
    output[i] = "household_" + index + "_" + v.id;
    i++;
  });
});
output;
```

produces this:

`["household_foo_1", "household_foo_3", "household_bar_2", "household_bar_4"]`

I get the strings I need; I can take it from here.